# How do you view/extract iOS crash logs with Xcode 15?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got a phone with some crash logs on it, with any version of Xcode other than 15.0, I can instantly see and access them like so:

[image: Xcode 14]

However using Xcode 15 with the same phone attached there is nothing to see:

[image: XCode 15]

Clicking the Open button for either the Other Logs or the Unsymbolicated Logs show nothing, they are both empty.
Where then and how to find and get the crash logs with Xcode 15?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: For me, I just open latest version of Xcode 14 in Sonoma (there is a way to do that by right clicking on Xcode 14 and double clicking some file, ask ChatGPT or Bard) and symbolicate a log.

Comment: Does showing the directory in Finder work? Xcode might be hiding your logs for some reason

Comment: @black
Sorry for the very late reply, only just noticed. No I didn't, did you?

Answer (score -2):

When you link your iphone,this path can find crash-logs:

> ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

Answer (score -3):

go to Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> your device -> Open recent Logs

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not an answer because that’s precisely what OP did. Furthermore, even if the log is there, opening it does not allow me to view the log, just “open in project” which isn’t always helpful at all